# Understanding Visual Studio Mac ⇧⌘O, F10 shortcut key for stepping over code when debugging

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Either I'm really dumb or this is really weird, reading the documentation on Visual Studio Code shortcut keys for stepping through code when debugging they posted this "⇧⌘O, F10" as the shortcut for stepping over a line of code. What exactly does this short cut mean, Shift/Command/0/F10 or two different options. Every time I press F10 I got a volume toggle dialog screen that pops up regardless of being included in a key combination. Was hoping someone could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, in keyboard settings there is an option using F1,F2 etc. keys as standard function keys on external keyboard layouts and that did the trick!
[image]